# Is it possible to save the lyx documents so they open with the program after I reboot?

Tags: lyx

For example, in some programs, you can save a "project" which keeps all open scripts or tabs open even after you reboot.  I have many I am working on, but when I reboot my computer I have to go find them all one by one.  Is it possible to preserve the work environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Tools > Preferences, check the option "Load opened files from last session", and click on "Save".

Here is a screenshot of the option (which for me is unchecked):

[image]

Note that this preference has nothing to do with rebooting your computer, but rather restarting LyX, whether it is before or after a reboot. You can add LyX to open on startup and maybe that would get you what you want.